# pre_get_posts : only get posts by wp_usermeta value

Tags: custom-field, query, pre-get-posts, meta-value

I've added a meta field on my authors (`company`). How can I only display the posts written by authors with a specific company value (`company1` or `company2` for example)?

I would like to do that within the [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WP_Query Object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) does not support retrieving posts by `author_meta` so neither will the [`pre_get_posts` hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). The next best thing would be to run a quick [WP_User_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) and get all users by the specific `author_meta` then limit our query to only pull posts from those authors. Here's what that would look like:

```
/**
 * Modify Queries 
 *
 * @param WP_Query Object $query
 */
function theme_pgp( $query ) {

    // If we're on admin side, return
    if( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Only apply to main queries
    if( $query->is_main_query() ) {

        // Get all users with a Company field
        $users = new WP_User_Query( array(
            'meta_key'      => 'company',
            'meta_value'    => 'company1',
            'fields'        => 'ID',
        ) );
        $authors = $users->get_results();

        if( ! empty( $authors ) ) {
            $query->set( 'author__in', $authors );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'theme_pgp' );
```

Comment: Looks like you posted few seconds before me, deleted mine ;-) ps: I don't think `ids` is supported, so we should use `ID` or `id` instead and `meta_query` would be needed for multiple values.

Comment: @birgire Good catch, updated!